# What to do with sore muscles

Tags: exercise, muscle-soreness

Say I have done some exercise and the next few days I am rather sore in certain muscles.

What is the best thing to do about that? Let them rest (avoid using them)? Use them a lot? Exercise more? Rub them? Hot bath?

Comment: Check for a possible D-vitamin defiency with a doctor just in case, especially if you don't get much exposure to sun.

Comment: This thread is littered with upvoted misinformation.  Check out [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/my-legs-still-ache-3-4-days-after-legs-day/11687#11687) answer for some information backed up with scientific research.

Comment: @Doc Cool, thanks. That was a very interesting read :)

Answer (score 13):

**Prevent them from getting sore in the first place**

- [Bananas](http://www.ehow.com/how_2178765_recover-sore-muscles.html)

Eat bananas after a workout. A healthy source of potassium is essential to prevent muscle soreness. If you have ever drank (alcohol) heavily you may have also experienced muscle soreness. This is due to losing a lot of electrolytes (salt, potassium) due to the diuretic effects of alcohol.

- [B Vitamins](http://www.ehow.com/how_2178765_recover-sore-muscles.html)

B vitamins are also important to eat after strenuous exercise. Especially B1 (thiamine) as a deficiency will cause sore muscles.

- A cool after-workout swim (my personal anecdote)

I don't have an official source to back this up but I find that a swim in cool water after a strenuous exercise helps to cut down on the after-workout soreness. The combination of cool water and non-strenuous workout to get a good supply of oxygen/blood to the taxed muscles works wonders.

- [Properly cool down after a workout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooling_down)

When you do workouts that push your heart into the [anaerobic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaerobic_exercise) range (think faster than a light jog) your body's oxygen intake will max out and it will start metabolizing anaerobically (without oxygen). The byproduct of anaerobic metabolism is still a [controversial topic (due to traditional teaching vs current research)](http://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/lactate.html) but it's basically what causes the 'burn' you feel from a hard workout. If you don't take the steps to process the byproduct of an anaerobic workout you'll feel more sore the next day. That's why going from a sprint to a dead stop is a bad idea.

So how do you recover after an anaerobic workout? Do a proper cool-down aerobic workout (like a light jog) to provide the oxygen and circulation your body needs to process those byproducts created through the anaerobic (or strenuous) exercise.

- [Stretching](http://people.bath.ac.uk/masrjb/Stretch/stretching_4.html)

Stretch before you workout. Not static stretches (long hard stretches in a relaxed state) but dynamic stretches (short quick stretches where you flex the muscles) or else you'll elongate your muscles too much and increase your risk of ligament pain/injury.

- [Warm up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warming_up)

Properly warm up your muscles. If you have ever worked out with a heart rate monitor you probably already know that your body doesn't go from 0-max very well. It takes some time for your circulatory system to fully adjust to the increased intensity.

- [Increase your fitness level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VO2_max)

The concept is pretty simple. The better your body can circulate and provide oxygen to muscles, the better it will be able to process the byproducts of the strenuous workout.

How you do so depends on what you're building up to. For instance:

If you are training for long distance running, then you'll want to do more workouts in the aerobic range mainly due to the fact that more Type II muscle means more weight to carry and more resources (energy) you'll need to sustain the pace. As you may see on this site, many people like to bring up the topic of 'runners high' where you feel like you can keep going forever without getting tired. This is mainly due to the fact that your body is completely warmed up and effectively metabolizing in the aerobic (and therefore not creating any nasty byproducts) as well as releasing endorphins. As long as you can keep going without any functional issues (muscle strain, ligament pain, boredom) and you can maintain a healthy energy level, *theoretically* you **could** go forever. Unfortunately, your body doesn't have the ability to properly maintain itself (digestion, recovery, etc) during exercise. This is due to your body focusing it's resources on the '[sympathetic nervous system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_nervous_system)' during exercise as opposed to the 'parasympathetic nervous system'.

If you're geared more toward weight lifting, higher intensity, short burst exercises, or other types of anaerobic activities like sprinting; The hard-and-fast rule is, 'the harder you workout the harder you will be able to workout'. This is mainly due to the fact that the more you push into the anaerobic range the better your body will adjust to be able to handle processing of the anaerobic byproducts. Fewer residual byproducts means less after-workout soreness.

If you want specifics on 'why' that rule holds true, google the term 'anaerobic threshold' and spend some time reading up on the topic. Most people (including myself) were brought up to believe 'no pain no gain'. That is only partially true. You will feel some soreness/stiffness when you first start no matter what you do but pain does not equal progress. If you focus on increasing fitness *first* before strength you will have a much less painful path to progress (and you will probably be more healthy overall).

---

If you're already sore, don't completely avoid activity. Moving around will help loosen up the muscles a bit and recover faster, just take it easy and let your body recover.

**Update:**

I just stumbled on a [Recovery Guide by the USTA (United States Tennis Association)](http://assets.usta.com/assets/1/15/recovery_project_coaches_booklet.pdf) that covers all of these points and more in detail. Including CNS (Central Nervous System) and psychological fatigue - which I neglected to cover in my answer.

Comment: phew, that was long

Comment: That probably sums up anything I would recommend.

Comment: B vitamins are good for the nervous system when it has been subjected to stress. Also please make sure to check for a possible D-vitamin defiency as that can cause widespread soreness which may have similarities with fybromyalgia.

Comment: Stretching, warming up, and cooling down (literally, with ice/cool water), haven't been shown to have any impact on soreness (see [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11643/my-legs-still-ache-3-4-days-after-legs-day/11687#11687) answer).

Comment: @Doc Your answer that you linked to confuses muscule tissue damage with muscle recovery; injury/inflammation != DOMS. Light dynamic stretches (ie not static stretching as referenced in the study you linked) and a warm-up increase circulation, it's more for preventing injury than reducing muscle fatigue. From your answer, I think you'd agree that good circulation is important to muscle function. The cool-down recovery has actually been proven by Stanford (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8J6ov48rG0). Recovery doesn't come from icing locally but by bringing core temps back down to normal.

Comment: What about massages? I haven't been properly warming up and cooling down, but I have been doing these other things. Over time my muscles were getting tight to the point of thinking my tendons when injured somehow. Plus every once in a while a knot would show up then very slowly go away. Regardless I was getting much faster (after a limping for the first few minutes) so I didn't want to stop. After the goal race was done I took time off but the problems didn't go away until I started doing recovery runs and massages. Aren't these necessary? Could warming up/ cooling down replace these?

Answer (score 6):

Muscle soreness after exercise is a very common symptom of a strenuous exercise, and is usually indicative of a "good" workout, i.e. one in which you've stressed the muscles to the point at which they will grow stronger. The cause of the soreness is currently unknown. Previous hypotheses involving lactic acid and muscle spasms have been demonstrated to be incorrect.

You can provide temporary relief using warm compresses and gentle massaging of the affected muscle, but the soreness will persist until about 72 hours. The best thing to do is to stick to a regular routine; soreness is notably worse the first time a muscle group is significantly stressed. Note that while continuing to exercise will stave off soreness, overstressing can lead to sprains and tears.

Answer (score 6):

There are two major types of soreness

> 1. From a very good workout
> 2. Over training.

Depending what is the cause of your soreness you have to take appropriate actions.

If its of type 1, give it rest for roughly 4 days(infact it depends on the muscle/muscle group that is/are sore) to recuperate, do not work the muscle and strain it again.

During the recuperation time, actual growth and adaptation(of the muscles to higher levels of stress and strain) takes place. So rest is very important. Which leads to **not to train harder or more often.**

Type 2 occurs when you work a muscle too often to allow it to fully recuperate, you have to consult a doctor, because he might prescribe a pain killer or some medicine. Take lot of rest, sometimes weeks of it.

One important factor: Trained muscles recover from fatigue faster than untrained muscles.
So the better you get at exercising the faster your recovery rate will be and the more intense your training can become.

Comment: I agree with the last paragraph but you suggest getting a prescription for pain killers to overcome muscle fatigue? Pain is a perfectly natural response that tells you to 'take it easy'. The way to get rid of it is to give your body what it needs to recover faster which includes, rest, water, electrolytes, and nutrients. Munching on pain killers only dulls the symptoms and may produce additional side-effects, it doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 5):

Keep working out according to your schedule (assuming there's a 48-72 hour recovery period after each session -- if not, get a new schedule). It's not harmful, and might even make the soreness go away sooner.

Answer (score 3):

An [ice bath](http://sharkfitness.wordpress.com/2009/01/29/after-exercise-ice-bath-recovery/) may help against muscle soreness:

> The ice bath is thought to:
>
> - Constrict blood vessels and flush waste products, like lactic acid,    out of the affected tissues
> - Decrease metabolic activity and slow down    physiological processes
> - Reduce swelling and tissue breakdown

Comment: Why would an ice bath help relieve muscle soreness? Please update your answer with information from the link you provided.

Comment: Good point there. I've updated it. I'll work on this more later.

Comment: No joke, this answer have substance proven by research. Apparently recovery can be fast-tracked by reducing your body's core temperature. It may also explain why swimming in cool water helps me recover faster. Brought to you by Stanford http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8J6ov48rG0.

Comment: What about a cold shower immediately after a workout ?

Answer (score 1):

What to do depends on how sore your muscles are, how long they've been sore and your prior experience with sore muscles.  The easy answer is to rest, but it may not be the best advice for your specific situation.  I've always felt that you should continue exercising, but with the focus on areas not directly related to the 'sore' muscle area, this builds an exercise pattern that will provide long term benefit, help increase your pain threshold (pain management is key to any aggressive exercise program) and gives those 'sore' muscles time to heal.

Make sure you're hydrating enough and getting sufficient protein to help reduce the intensity and duration of muscle soreness.

Answer (score 1):

I started with a trainer a few months ago and starting out, I would get SO sore. Using a foam roller really helped (before and after).

You can find different workouts with a [foam roller here](http://www.bodybuilding.com/exercises/finder/lookup/filter/equipment/id/14/equipment/foam-roll).

Comment: It would help if you would list some of the exercises.

Answer (score 0):

When I am sore I like to recover with a pool session. You only need to get in waist deep and you do a series of stretching exercises (quads, hamstrings, hip flexors, calves, etc.). The water resistance helps with the lactic acid build up. This works the best for me and hopefully may be a good option for your soreness as well.

Comment: Do you happen to have an article to support your claim about water resistance and lactic acid build up?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one's mentioned Epsom Salt bath soaks for the mineral content, as Epsom Salt is a dissolvable form of Magnesium. This really helps me with soreness.

Taking vitamin B6 orally may help with uptake, and Calcium works synergistically with the Magnesium.

Here's [an article](http://www.getbig.com/articles/faq-min1.htm) with overall information about minerals and bodybuilding, but you may wish to try and get more updated suggestions for how to take what you need from your doctor.

Comment: It would be good if you cite the crucial parts of the article, content on the Internet often is subject to link rot.

Answer (score -1):

All types of exercise will eventually make you sore and that is meant to happen. As Mark Ripptoe says, "you don't get strong from lifting weights, you get strong from recovering from lifting weights". An important factor of lifting/exercise is recovery, sleep, and proper nutrition. Your recovery will include things that help relax the muscles such as message, hot baths (switching from hot to cold if you are able to), heating pads and ice, or rubs like tiger balm. Another thing that will really help your recovery is planning to go for walks. Going on a long relaxing but brisk walk at least 1-2 times a week is just as important as planning the days that you lift on. Walking helps circulation and will reduce pain in your muscles. Your nutrition is going to include making sure you are getting the right macro nutrients such as calories, fats, carbs, and proteins as well as making sure you get your micro nutrients from lots of vegetables. As far as supplementation that is very individualized. The only way to know would be to get blood work and have a doctor that specializes in doing full spectrum analysis. This will tell you what you are deficient it. On the other hand it needs to be updated every 6 months to stay relevant which is rather costly. One supplement that can help most people (except those with health issues) is creatine monohydrate. Creatine will help you produce more atp which means more energy for building those gains. Glutamine also pairs well with creatine in maximizing its effects. Lastly getting enough sleep is very important. Lastly, if you are experiencing extreme pain that lasts for days after exercising then you need to be reevaluating your programing and getting advice from a knowledgable strength coach. All the best.